# DayNight mode not working for Presentation dialog on second screen

Tags: java, android, multiple-monitors

I've got a small test app to test day/night themes in a device with two screens.

I've got a `themes.xml`

```xml
    <style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    </style>

   <style name="Theme.MyApp.CFS">
        <!-- NOTE: The theme is loading the light mode...-->
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/vivid_tangerine</item>
    </style>
```

And the same `theme.xml` in `values-night` folder, with a different color

```xml
   <style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    </style>

   <style name="Theme.MyApp.CFS">
        <!-- NOTE: The theme is loading the dark mode...-->
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/malibu_2</item>
    </style>
```

My `MainActivity` extends `AppCompatActivity` and has this code on the `onCreate`

```java
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        @SuppressLint("WrongConstant") DisplayManager displayManager = (DisplayManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.DISPLAY_SERVICE);
        var presentationDisplays = displayManager.getDisplays(DisplayManager.DISPLAY_CATEGORY_PRESENTATION);
        var pres = new Pres(this, presentationDisplays[0], R.style.Theme_MyApp_CFS);
        pres.show();
    }
```

The theme defined for it is the `Theme.MyApp`, set in the manifest file.

This `Pres` class is just a class that extends `Presentation` and sets the content view to a layout that's using the `colorBackground` attribute and showing on the secondary display.

```xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/second_screen_theme_wrapper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="?android:attr/colorBackground"
    android:orientation="vertical">
...
```

The problem is that the presentation doesn't respect the night mode toggle and shows the theme as if it were the light mode.
The main activity screen shows the theme with the correct night mode applied (shows the according bg color) but the presentation/dialog doesn't.

Is there a way to pass the theme file that's in night mode specifically or something else? Or do I need to create two themes on `values/theme.xml` for day and night mode and pass one to the constructor of the presentation accordingly?

The `minSdk` is set to 21 and `targetSdk` to 33, in case that's relevant.

Answer (score 0):

I think its not working because you defined 'android:colorBackground' in a different style named 'Theme.MyApp.CFS'. Just define it in the theme itself and it should work fine.

```
    <style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- NOTE: The theme is loading the light mode...-->
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/vivid_tangerine</item>
    </style>
```

instead of :

```
   <style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
   </style>

   <style name="Theme.MyApp.CFS">
        <!-- NOTE: The theme is loading the light mode...-->
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/vivid_tangerine</item>
   </style>
```

**Method 2 :**

You can achieve this with another method. You have defined the attribute in a separate style named 'Theme.MyApp.CFS'. You can add the style attribute instead of background attribute to LinearLayout.

```
   <LinearLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/second_screen_theme_wrapper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        style="@style/Theme.MyApp.CFS">
   ...
```

Comment: Neither methods are what I wanted.
For the first one, I'm just defining a subset of the theme for that specific component (`.CFS`) and it should inherit from the `Theme.MyApp` (I've set it with parent as that and still has the same behavior).

The second one doesn't work as well, because I'm defining [theme attributes](https://youtu.be/Owkf8DhAOSo?feature=shared&t=216) and not style attributes.

Comment: have you tried android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApp.CFS" in LinearLayout